# How to access the long s from the gentium font?

Tags: fonts, font-encodings

The [gentium font](https://software.sil.org/gentium/download/) contains glyphs for the long s (U+017F) character and it works fine with XeLaTeX. But I'm using pdflatex and the [`gentium-tug`](https://ctan.org/pkg/gentium-tug?lang=en) package and I can't figure out how to access this glyph. Here's an mwe where I've tried using the definition from `symbols-a4.pdf` (p. 259) which seems to work for lmodern but not gentium:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gentium}
\newcommand{\gentiumlongs}{{\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\char115}}
\newcommand{\lmlongs}{{\fontencoding{TS1}\fontfamily{lmr}\selectfont\char115}}

\begin{document}
\gentiumlongs

\lmlongs
\end{document}
```

I can imagine two reasons for this:

- I'm not accessing it correctly, I should be using `\char` with some different argument or something entirely different. In that case, what is the right command and how does one find this out?
- The version of the gentium fonts that the `gentium-tug` package uses is different/outdated and does not include the relevant glyph. In that case, can I 'inject' the full/correct font into a local copy of the package?

Comment: You would at least need `\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont` just `\fontencoding{TS1}` on its own won't select a font

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I see. It doesn't work either way, and I assumed the `\selectfont` was just for the `\fontfamily`. Edited.

Comment: also you can never get access to all the characters, the gentium plus doc says "In total, over 4,200 glyphs are included," the T1 and TS1 ecoded subsets for pdflatex have 256 each, so you are missing a few.

Comment: You file reports: `Missing character: There is no s in font ts1-gentiumplus-regular`

Comment: Is there something holding you back from just using XeLaTeX (or LuaLaTeX)?

Comment: note `\char115` is just `s` no need to use `\char` here.

Comment: @Mico, Not really, but it seemed plausible that I was overlooking some other simple solution.

Comment: You can check for the available characters using the `fonttable` package and then calling, for example, `\xfonttable{TS1}{gentium}{m}{n}`. Sadly, the long s is not mapped in this encoding.

Answer (score 1):

There is no long s in the [official code table for the TS1 encoding,](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/encguide.pdf#subsection.A.2) although `cmr` and `lmr` both have it.

The Type 1 versions of Gentium therefore do not seem to come with a long s glyph.

By default, due to technical debt from the ’80s, TeX ignores when the font you are using lacks a character, and silently adds a line to the middle of the `.log` file.  To override this behavior, you want to add this command near the top of your document:

```
\tracinglostchars=3
```

You can instead use `\tracinglostchars=2` to at least print a warning message to the console.

Normally, though, you’d enable a character such as this with commands such as:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=3 % Error if a symbol is missing from the font!
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{microtype}

\DeclareTextSymbol{\textlongs}{TS1}{"73}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\textlongs}{TS1}

\newunicodechar{ſ}{\textlongs}

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page number

\begin{document}
\noindent
\textit{Oliver Twiſt}, again, is directed againſt the poor-law and work-houſe ſyſtems, and in our opinion with much unfairneſs.  The abuſes which he ridicules are not only much exaggerated, but in nineteen caſes out of twenty do not at all exiſt.  Boz so rarely mixes up politics, or panders to vulgar prejudices about ſerious things, that we reget to ſee him participate in an outcry which is partly factious, partly ſentimental, partly intereſted.  The beſetting ſin of `white-waiſtcoated' guardians is profuſion, not parſimony; and this always muſt be the caſe where perſons have to be generous out of funds to which individually they are ſmall contributors.  After all, the proof of the pudding is in the eating: one week's poorhouſe pot-luck fattens a pauper brat up to ſuch a {\textlongs}ucking-pig nicety, that its own parent, like Saturn, longs to eat it up with more than kiſſes.

\end{document}
```

[image: Latin Modern sample]